# What are the main points of hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

What are the main features of hibernate one must know?
I guess people misunderstood my question. Here are the features I know :

- save/update
- query (hql or criteria)
- lazy/eager loading
- transaction

Are there others?

Comment: All the impotent features are pointed out in question and answers. I feel like something important is missed. You can `switch the database` anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the most important things to know are:

- How to annotate your entities (know the basic annotations and have a good reference for the others)
- How to build HQL (or JPQL) queries

I would also add the following to your list:

- Session and SessionFactory (EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory if you use JPA)
- Caching (second level cache and query cache)

Otherwise, I think you hit the major points.

Answer (score 4):

Check [here](http://www.hibernate.org/). It basically gives you a standard interface through which you application can use a database engine. So even if you change the database, you do not have to modify the code on your application side...